# Is it possible to import one grammar in another grammar definition using PEGKit?

Tags: pegkit

I would like to use one grammar definition as an extension point to my own.

With Antlr you can import grammar files in your own grammar definition.

Is it possible to do the same with PEGKit?

Answer (score 0):

Creator of [PEGKit](https://github.com/itod/pegkit) here.

Sorry, no. There's no **Import** or **Inheritance** mechanism currently in PEGKit. And honestly, it's not likely to appear soon (or probably at all).

It's not that I don't think this is an interesting feature, but given my current development priorities and responsibilities, I will not have time to add it.